# Vba Stock in Workbook.open [Continues if I press F5]

Tags: excel, vba

When I tried to open an excel file from my macro: I have a **1004** problem, and if I debug the code and press **F5** to continue the file is opened without any problem, also If I debug the code line by line works.

```
Sub openFile2(ruta, fich, destino As Worksheet)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim aux As String
    aux = ruta & "\" & fich
    ChDir ruta
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fich       

End Sub
```

My values

**Ruta**

> "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Swap\@&&Informes&&@\Informes 2G\Input"

**fich**

> "CNA_GsmRel_Z2_23052013.xls"

Also i tried with:

```
    aux = ruta & "\" & fich
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=aux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Workbooks.Open` requires the complete path `Filename` so it should be `Workbooks.Open(FileName:=aux)` instead of `Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fich)`

Declaring workbook variable `wkb` gives you control over the workbook for further manipulation.

Save the workbook which houses the code before running the code.

Use below code which is more robust.

```
Sub sample()
    ruta = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Swap\@&&Informes&&@\Informes 2G\Input"
    fich = "CNA_GsmRel_Z2_23052013.xls"
    openFile2 ruta, fich, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

End Sub

Sub openFile2(ruta, fich, destino As Worksheet)

    Dim aux As String
    aux = ruta & "\" & fich

    Dim wkb As Workbook

    If IsWorkBookOpen(aux) Then
        Set wkb = Workbooks(fich)
    Else
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=aux)
    End If

End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0: IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70: IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I use the full path,but When i run the macro i have the proble **1004** if I debug the error and press F5 to continue It works without any problem and open the file.

Comment: @JonathanRaulTapiaLopez When workbook is closed you have to use Full path & when workbook is open you have to use workbook name.

Comment: Ohh it is the solution the file was opened